# Is it possible to use context and labels in Liquibase for Node.js?

Tags: java, node.js, liquibase

I was wondering if I am able to do something like this in Liquibase for Node.js?

```
liquibase.update(new Contexts(name), new LabelExpression(version));
```

Also in your opinion would you say that the use of Liquibase API is limited in Node.js compared to the one in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can provide these as config data. Find more information here: [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/liquibase).
In `myConfig` you can add `labels` and `contexts`.